# $\simeq$ in "Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms" by David MacKay

Tags: notation, asymptotics

I am trying to work through *Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms* by David MacKay.

However, I am confused by his notation

$$
\simeq.
$$

For example, on the very first page he uses it to state a form of Stirling's approximation:
$$
x! \simeq x^x \exp(-x).
$$

From this statement, I know that he cannot mean asymptotically equal to, used as
$$ f(x) \sim g(x)$$ to mean $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1,$$ as Stirling's approximation is in fact $$x! \sim x^x \exp(-x) \sqrt{2 \pi x}.$$

My working hypothesis is that
$$ f(x) \simeq g(x)$$ means something like $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\log(f(x))}{\log(g(x))} = 1,$$ but I have tried to look online and haven't found any confirmation. I was curious if anyone more familiar either with this book or asymptotic notation could clarify?